# Format returned date in Angular owl-date-time picker

Tags: javascript, angular, datetimepicker

From the below, you can see that I'm using the NEW (1.5.1) `owl-date-time` picker to return a selected value to the input box.  All is well, except that it's returned as M/d/yyyy and I would like it shown to the user as yyyy-MM-dd.

The [attr.value] does it correctly but doesn't alter what is shown on screen (which I'm guessing is overridden by the `[(ngModel)]` and I can't add the date pipe in to that line without generating an error - Any ideas?

```
            <input
              id="tx_date"
              type="text"
              class="mt-25"
              [(ngModel)]="tx_date"
              [owlDateTime]="txDate"
              [owlDateTimeTrigger]="txDate"
              [max]="maxDate"
              [placeholder]="'yyyy-mm-dd'"
              [attr.value]="tx_date | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'"
              [attr.disabled]="isSelected.date ? null : 'disabled'">
              <owl-date-time
                pickerType="calendar"
                #txDate>
              </owl-date-time>
```

Comment: I've found this link in the docs to setting the locale https://danielykpan.github.io/date-time-picker/#locale-formats
Hope it'll help

Comment: Thanks @t3__rry - I've altered the locale to `en` which presents it ad dd/mm/yyyy which is preferable to the US alternative but didn't really resolve the issue.

Comment: is there way to achieve this from html side?